# set mixed mode authentication in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, mixed-mode, sa

Is it possible to set mixed mode authentication from within SQLCMD?

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express last week because I forgot my old installation password.  It didn't help.  I've been through a ton of stuff just trying to get back to square one.

I think my last step would be to reset my sa password or account, but the command I have used doesn't seem to be working. I think it might be because my SQL instance is windows auth only.  I have SQLCMD open; is it possible to set my instance to mixed mode from there?

Edit: I really just want to get into my DB.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: No, but you can [follow these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: easy for you to say

Comment: haha, thanks; that got me in

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15